# AWS ELB http works, but https not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elb

I requested a SSL certificate in AWAS Certificate Manager with my own domain, then setup an Elastic Load Balancer forwarding to an EC2 instance which has a Python API running on port 5070.

**Load Balancer**
[image]

**443 Rule**
[image]

**Target Group**
[image]

I can get response from http URL, but https is not working, got the below error

```
The requested URL can’t provide a secure connection
The URL sent an invalid response.

Learn more about this problem.

net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

**Any idea on this problem?**

Comment: can you also provide the 443 forwarding details?

Comment: Sure, added, the second screen

Comment: Have you tried changing the Forwarding rule HTTPS: 5070
since the instance under ALB will only accepts request from 5070

Comment: @EdcelCabreraVista yes, I added a listener (HTTPS:5070) to same target group. Now, got this error "The requested URL can't be reached
The service might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."